# C# SQL Server database with relationships - insert statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, relationship

I'm trying to build a little application in C# with a SQL Server database.

I created 2 tables:

- `Firm` with an `ID` (primary key and `Identity`) and a column `Name`
- `Worker` also with an `ID`, `Forename` and `Surname`

In next step I created a relationship between them.

I can add a `Firm` but in case of adding a worker I get an exception.

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Worker_Firm". The conflict occurred in database "TestDB", table "dbo.Firm", column 'ID'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Adding `Firm`:

```
string sqlIns = "INSERT INTO Firm (Name) VALUES (@name)";

conn.Open();

SqlCommand cmdIns = new SqlCommand(sqlIns, conn);
cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@name", "MyFirm");

cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmdIns.Dispose();
cmdIns = null;

conn.Close();
```

Adding `Worker`:

```
string sqlIns = "INSERT INTO Worker(Forename, Surname) VALUES (@forename, @surname)";

conn.Open();

SqlCommand cmdIns = new SqlCommand(sqlIns, conn);
cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@forename", "MyForename");
cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@surname", "MySurname");

cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmdIns.Dispose();
cmdIns = null;

conn.Close();
```

How can I set the relationship between the worker and the firm into the statement? I doesent see any property like `Firm_ID`.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll need to post your database schema. Your error message suggests it's very likely a foreign key column (FirmID or similar) is present in your Worker table and needs to be incorporated into your INSERT statement. What do you mean when you say you can't see any such property?

Comment: It's called `Surname` (not `Surename`) for the last name of a person, and the first name is usually called `FirstName` (`Forename` is not really very widely used in the English langauge)

Comment: @marc_s I use forename all the time.

Comment: @podiluska: British? US? Canadian? Irish? Australian? New Zealander? Or what kind of English-speaker are you? (just curiuos - I've never heard it being used, in US/Canadian English)

Comment: @marc_s English English! :) See it all the time on forms.